# Passing Int and List variables to VBscript

Tags: c#, vbscript

I'm passing variables from my C# code to my VBscript using `process.StartInfo.Arguments` but it only passes string variables.

Here's my sample code and it do work for passing strings.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\Libraries\\Document\\Merge.vbs";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\\Libraries\\Document\\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = FileName;
process.Start();
```

How can I possibly pass `int` and `List<string>` to my VBscript without using `startinfo.Arguments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are always string values you will need to convert them to a string in order to pass them in.

For example a list can be translated by using `string.Join`

```
int myInt
List<string> myStringList;
List<int> myIntList;

string intAsString = myInt.ToString();
string stringListAsString = string.Join(",",myStringList);
// using System.Linq
string stringListAsString = string.Join(",",myIntList.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

To decode the other end you will need the split function assuming you've copied the arguments into matching variables.

```
myInt = CInt(intAsString)
myStringList = Split(stringListAsString,",")
myIntList = Split(intListAsString,",")

for a = LBound(myIntList) to Ubound(myIntList)
  myIntList(a) = CInt(myIntList(a))
next a
```

If the shear volume of arguments are too great you can always write them to a temporary file and pass the filename into your VB script

Comment: Tnx. I'll try this one

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work this way. Arguments to a program are always string. That means that you have to convert all your arguments to string and parse them in your vbscript

Comment: Can you give me a sample where in I can pass List<string> as a simple string and add to my List in my vbscript?

Comment: for example, you could create a semi-colon separated string of your `List<string>` instance. e.g. `string.Join(";", yourList)` . In the vb-script, you have to parse this semi-colon separated string again

Comment: How about I'm getting my List from database. Sorry, I'm so new with vb that why I don't really get it..

Comment: I can't help you any further as you lack of the basic knowledge. sorry

Comment: I've get how to pass list but I cant able to split all the strings

Comment: @KuriyamaMirai try [the split function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp)